# Wordpress loading external jQuery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is it possible to load external jQuery files while allowing those files to use the "$" sign? Without changing the external jQuery files?

Currently, I'm using the wp_enqueue_script function to add the scripts to my site, but since WordPress runs jQuery in compatibility mode the scripts do not have access to the "$" and are forced to use "jQuery" instead. I know how to fix this issue for the local jQuery files on the website, but I have no clue on external files which I cannot edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use noConflict() in jQuery?
If not then try with the following line of code

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
</script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Again, i cannot modify the scripts as they are from an external source. I need to allow those files to use $ as jQuery without editing them.